# Livepatch isn't available for Non-LTS release

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I just release-upgraded to a non-LTS release of Ubuntu, and I tried to turn on livepatch but it just doesn't work. I turned on token and everything, but doesn't work... any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [LivePatch Datasheet](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/ef19ede0-Datasheet_Livepatch_AW_Web_30.07.18.pdf):

> Product Overview
>
> The Canonical Livepatch Service delivers live kernel patching
> to Ubuntu LTS systems without the need to reboot.

Unfortunately, Livepatch is available **ONLY** for LTS releases
(clearly marked as LTS on [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases))

Livepatch is **NOT** available for non-LTS releases.

Comment: Yesssss! thank you for the answer!