# Installing Groovy Gorila from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.10

I have Ubuntu 20.04. I want to install ubuntu 20.10 Groovy Gorilla without uninstalling 20.04 and just want to update it . How can I do that?

Comment: Hey Python is cool! Open "*Software & Updates*" app and click on "*Updates*". There will be a dropdown option named "*Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:*". Change the option to "*For any new version*". Also I hope that you know the difference between an LTS release and a normal release. If you don't, please read this: https://askubuntu.com/q/16366

Comment: Yes I know the difference between LTS and normal. But 20.10 Works better on my laptop

Comment: So did you upgrade to 20.10? @Pythoniscool Also, don't forget to tag my username when you're replying to my comment (like this: @technastic_tc).

Comment: @technastic_tc No. First I have to update this and total is 300MB. It is too much and I don't have time. I wish I could upgrade with terminal

Comment: You can try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in terminal for casual updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116006/discussion-between-technastic-tc-and-python-is-cool).

Comment: Hi. Why live patch isn't availble on this release?

Comment: Does that mean it isn't safe?

Comment: Do read this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1290286/1103140 If there's no Live Patch, that doesn't mean it's unsafe. The most popular advantage of Live Patch is that you can apply critical kernel patches without rebooting. So when there's no Live Patch, you need to restart to apply critical kernel patches. I personally don't feel restarting my system for applying patches as a dealbreaker. But opinions do vary..